# Column selection and URL modification

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML table representing a database table and a sidebar which holds different anchors ready to perform CRUD operations on click.

Because the hrefs in the anchors aren't in general valid for all columns I have written a script which automatically inserts the id of a selected column into the hrefs:

```
/localhost/image/var/edit => /localhost/image/4/edit
```

The code I have written works but it isn't very clean and smart :( Could somebody take a look and say where I have space of improvement?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('table tr').click(function(){
    $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    var name = $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').html();

    $('.image_bar ul li a').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href').replace('var', name));
    });
});
</script>
```

How could I improve the `td:nth-child(2)` selector and the long line modifying the link?

EDIT:

```
<aside class="left image_bar">
<ul>
    {% if image is defined %}
    <li><a href="{{ path('AcmeCoreBundle_Image_index')}}">Bilder verwalten</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ path('AcmeCoreBundle_Image_show', { name: image.name }) }}">Bild betrachten</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ path('AcmeCoreBundle_Image_new') }}">Bild hinzufügen</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ path('AcmeCoreBundle_Image_edit', { name: image.name }) }}">Bild bearbeiten</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ path('AcmeCoreBundle_Image_delete', { name: image.name }) }}">Bild löschen</a></li>
    {% else %}
    <li><a href="{{ path('AcmeCoreBundle_Image_index')}}">Bilder verwalten</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ path('AcmeCoreBundle_Image_show', { name: 'var' }) }}">Bild betrachten</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ path('AcmeCoreBundle_Image_new') }}">Bild hinzufügen</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ path('AcmeCoreBundle_Image_edit', { name: 'var' }) }}">Bild bearbeiten</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ path('AcmeCoreBundle_Image_delete', { name: 'var' }) }}">Bild löschen</a></li>
    {% endif %}
</ul>
</aside>
```

As you see when having an available singe object (while editing, showing, deleting) the server side renders the right id/name into the href. Under circumstances when I only have a collection of objects or none object available, jquery has to do the rendering of the right urls. Also some URLs don't require an id (new, index)

Comment: `$('.image_bar ul li a')` selects all elements from document, not from the selected row. Are you sure that it is correct?

Comment: Yes, I have a sidebar which contains the hrefs to the action urls (new, edit, delete,...). The tables are selected above :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var $lastSelected = $([]);
    $('tr').click(function () { //tr tag is always inside a table
        $lastSelected.removeClass('selected'); //by caching this variable in the closure we don't need to traverse for it again
        $lastSelected = $(this).addClass('selected');
    });

    $('.image_bar a').click(function (e) { 
        var url = $(this).attr('href').split('var'), //both checks if var is there and prepares for the replacement
            name;
        if ($lastSelected.length === 0) {
            return url.length==1; //any urls that do not have var in them will still work
        }

        name = $lastSelected.children().eq(2).html();
        window.location = url.join(name);
    });
});
</script>
```

Here I am assuming your toolbar is outside of your table.

### About the changes:

1. `$(function () {` lets you move this script tag elsewhere in your document (perhaps to an external script)
2. By caching `$lastSelected`, fewer DOM traversals need to happen.
3. Knowing `$lastSelected` enables moving the `$.fn.each` call out of the tr click event by setting name inside of it.
4. Since the `.each` call is no longer in the click event, it can be a click event of its own (no more need to iterate over it).
5. Instead of modifying the `a` tags we can just set window.location since we are now in the event where the user has clicked.
6. Finally, if a row is not selected up front, the $lastSelected variable will not provide a valid name. Thus we shouldn't allow the link to be clicked if it contains `var` (done by the return statement).

Comment: Hi, I have added the twig-template of the sidebar. So you see how I thought the second part. This is also the reason why I have to use .each(). The ideal would be if I could set a js-compatible variable (at the moment the string 'var') and jQuery only has to insert this one. This would solve many things at once: 1. The user can't request a none existing side when not selected something 2. We would spare the parsing  Is there any solution which would come this idea next? Regards, Bodo

Comment: Nice answer! What's the difference between $(function() {}); and (function() {})()?

Comment: @Cygal: `(function () {}())` is an automatically executing anonymous function. `$(function () {})` is shorthand for `$(document).ready(function () {})` with the benefit that `$(document)` doesn't need to be created.

Comment: @BillBarry I knew about IIFEs but not about that shorthand. Thanks!

Comment: @BillBarry did you read my update? Any suggestions how I could implement a better placeholder?

Comment: @kyogron: The placeholder is fine, I don't think you need the .each anyway.

Comment: I tried the script and the last part didn't work :(. Another idea would be to set a var in the placeholder the first time and after this only the var has to get changed. Or I set the links from beginning in javascript